# Syntax error while iterating over data in an array

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I want to iterate over the data and place the resulting objects in an array in the "data" array. With this implementation, I get a syntax error. What am I doing wrong? Is my approach correct?

```
const data = [
            dictionary.map(item => {
                {
                    key: item.id,
                    engword: item.title,
                    rusword: item.body,
                    tags: 'beginner',
                }
            })
        ];
```

Comment: Can you please elaborate what you're trying to do, how does **dictionary** look like? The problem is obvious as the data will be an array that contains a sub-array as map will return an array, but I don't understand what you're trying to achieve from this as **dictionary** looks like an array of objects, so why would you iterate through it again, is it just to get some specific keys? otherwise just removing brakets from your implementations + change first curly brakets to parenthesis will do the job. Cheers

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `.map()` method returns an array, so you should assign it's value to `data` variable like this:

```
const data = dictionary.map(item => (
                {
                    key: item.id,
                    engword: item.title,
                    rusword: item.body,
                    tags: 'beginner',
                }
            ));
```

Also, you have double curly braces in your arrow function. When returning an object literal like that, you should wrap it in parentheses.

Comment: this does not solve my problem as it indicates a colon error, in the object

Comment: The code in my answer is working ok. Perhaps your error is originating elsewhere.

Comment: @MyGuitar can you show the error you're getting using the code above?

Comment: Thanks for the answer. If enclosed in parentheses, the syntax error goes away